# Альтернатива touch README.md под виндовс?

Tags: git

сейчас выдает ошибку touch :

```
Имя "touch" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1
+ touch README.md
+ ~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (touch:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Просто создайте пустой файл хоть в том же Блокноте

Comment: используйте bash оболочку, которая устанавливается, если ставить гит с git-scm. Тогда будут работать почти все туториалы и инструкции

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы используете PowerShell. Попробуйте это:

```
New-Item -ItemType file README.md
```

Comment: все равно ошибку выдает –

Comment: @towncitybr Какую?

Comment: ew-Item : Файл "C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\GitHub\project\README.md" уже существует.
строка:1 знак:1
+ New-Item -ItemType file README.md
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\lenovo\project\README.md:String) [New-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

Comment: @towncitybr Ошибка возникает, потому что файл уже существует

Comment: удалил, заново сделал . Файл реадми создался. Потом пишу touch README.md - также ошибка, что в вопросе будет

Comment: @towncitybr Так Вы же альтернативу спрашивали... Команда `touch` создаёт файл, но работает только в Unix-системах. Я предложил Вам вариант того, как можно создать файл в Windows. Файл Вы создали. Так зачем Вы вводите `touch` снова?

Comment: Если файл существует, то `touch` меняет у него дату модификации, а не падает с ошибкой.

Answer (score 0):

```
copy NUL README.md
```

Или можете просто создать файл без использования командной строки.

Comment: все равно ошибку выдает

Answer (score 0):

Создать пустой файл:

```
echo > README.md
```

Считать контент:

```
type README.md
```